Get maps to recognize my brand as a franchise with multiple locations
If I search for "Chick-fil-a" on google maps, the pop up list gives me  "see locations" option with the company logo. If you click on that option, maps will zoom out and show all chick-fil-a locations in that area
I own a franchise with 40 locations. How do I get google maps to recognize each location as the same brand? I want the "see locations" option to pop up when people search my company name
I am the primary owner of all 40 GMB locations. I matched all GMB listings with the exact name.
